OpenOCD: invalid subcommand error when flashing Arduino Due
I'm trying to flash an Arduino Due using ST-LINK and OpenOCD using the SWD (debug header). I connected ST-LINK and the Due as follows.
ST-LINK -> Due 
VCC -> IOREF (also tried connecting to VIN and +3V3 pins)  (red wire) 
PIN 3 (TRST) -> RESET (green wire) 
PIN 7 (SWDIO/TMS) -> TMS (blue wire) 
PIN 9 (SWCLK)  -> TCK (yellow wire) 
GND -> GND (brown wire)

My openocd-due.cfg is
source [find interface/stlink.cfg]

#transport type SWD
transport select hla_swd

#swd frequency
adapter speed 1800

#sam3x8e cpuid
set CPUTAPID 0x2ba01477

source [find target/at91sam3XXX.cfg]

I compiled my program using the following commands:
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -o a.elf main.c
$ arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex -j .text -j .data a.elf a.hex

I try to flash this program using the following command:
$ openocd -f openocd-due.cfg -c "program a.elf verify reset exit"

I keep getting the following error:
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Warn : Could not determine executable path, using configured BINDIR.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : clock speed 500 kHz
Info : STLINK V2J29S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.197910
Info : sam3.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for sam3.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0010004c msp: 0x20001000
** Programming Started **
flash
  flash bank bank_id driver_name base_address size_bytes chip_width_bytes
            bus_width_bytes target [driver_options ...]
  flash banks
  flash init
  flash list
gdb_flash_program ('enable'|'disable')
nand
program <filename> [address] [pre-verify] [verify] [reset] [exit]
Error: invalid subcommand "write_image erase a.elf"
** Programming Failed **
shutdown command invoked
embedded:startup.tcl:583: Error: 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 583

EDIT: debug logs:
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
User : 13 1 options.c:63 configuration_output_handler(): debug_level: 3
User : 14 1 options.c:63 configuration_output_handler(): 
Warn : 15 1 options.c:131 find_exe_path(): Could not determine executable path, using configured BINDIR.
Debug: 16 1 options.c:132 find_exe_path(): BINDIR = /usr/local/bin
Debug: 17 1 options.c:244 add_default_dirs(): bindir=/usr/local/bin
Debug: 18 1 options.c:245 add_default_dirs(): pkgdatadir=/usr/local/share/openocd
Debug: 19 1 options.c:246 add_default_dirs(): exepath=/usr/local/bin
Debug: 20 1 options.c:247 add_default_dirs(): bin2data=../share/openocd
Debug: 21 1 configuration.c:42 add_script_search_dir(): adding /root/.config/openocd
Debug: 22 1 configuration.c:42 add_script_search_dir(): adding /root/.openocd
Debug: 23 1 configuration.c:42 add_script_search_dir(): adding /usr/local/bin/../share/openocd/site
Debug: 24 1 configuration.c:42 add_script_search_dir(): adding /usr/local/bin/../share/openocd/scripts
Debug: 25 2 configuration.c:97 find_file(): found openocd-due.cfg
Debug: 26 2 configuration.c:97 find_file(): found /usr/local/bin/../share/openocd/scripts/interface/stlink.cfg
Debug: 27 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - adapter driver hla
Debug: 29 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - hla_layout stlink
Debug: 31 2 hla_interface.c:242 hl_interface_handle_layout_command(): hl_interface_handle_layout_command
Debug: 32 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - hla_device_desc ST-LINK
Debug: 34 2 hla_interface.c:216 hl_interface_handle_device_desc_command(): hl_interface_handle_device_desc_command
Debug: 35 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - hla_vid_pid 0x0483 0x3744 0x0483 0x3748 0x0483 0x374b 0x0483 0x374d 0x0483 0x374e 0x0483 0x374f 0x0483 0x3752 0x0483 0x3753
Debug: 37 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select hla_swd
Debug: 38 2 hla_transport.c:205 hl_swd_transport_select(): hl_swd_transport_select
Debug: 39 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - adapter speed 1800
Debug: 41 2 core.c:1822 jtag_config_khz(): handle jtag khz
Debug: 42 2 core.c:1785 adapter_khz_to_speed(): convert khz to interface specific speed value
Debug: 43 2 core.c:1785 adapter_khz_to_speed(): convert khz to interface specific speed value
Debug: 44 2 configuration.c:97 find_file(): found /usr/local/bin/../share/openocd/scripts/target/at91sam3XXX.cfg
Debug: 45 2 configuration.c:97 find_file(): found /usr/local/bin/../share/openocd/scripts/target/swj-dp.tcl
Debug: 46 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 47 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 48 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 49 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - swd newdap sam3 cpu -irlen 4 -ircapture 0x1 -irmask 0xf -expected-id 0x2ba01477
Debug: 50 2 hla_tcl.c:111 jim_hl_newtap_cmd(): Creating New Tap, Chip: sam3, Tap: cpu, Dotted: sam3.cpu, 8 params
Debug: 51 2 hla_tcl.c:121 jim_hl_newtap_cmd(): Processing option: -irlen
Debug: 52 2 hla_tcl.c:121 jim_hl_newtap_cmd(): Processing option: -ircapture
Debug: 53 2 hla_tcl.c:121 jim_hl_newtap_cmd(): Processing option: -irmask
Debug: 54 2 hla_tcl.c:121 jim_hl_newtap_cmd(): Processing option: -expected-id
Debug: 55 2 core.c:1488 jtag_tap_init(): Created Tap: sam3.cpu @ abs position 0, irlen 0, capture: 0x0 mask: 0x0
Debug: 56 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - dap create sam3.dap -chain-position sam3.cpu
Debug: 57 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - target create sam3.cpu cortex_m -endian little -dap sam3.dap
Info : 58 2 target.c:5668 target_create(): The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Debug: 59 2 hla_target.c:203 adapter_target_create(): adapter_target_create
Debug: 60 2 hla_target.c:173 adapter_init_arch_info(): adapter_init_arch_info
Debug: 61 2 command.c:376 register_command(): command 'rtt' is already registered in '<global>' context
Debug: 62 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu configure -work-area-phys 0x20000000 -work-area-size 0x4000 -work-area-backup 0
Debug: 63 2 target.c:2172 target_free_all_working_areas_restore(): freeing all working areas
Debug: 64 2 target.c:2172 target_free_all_working_areas_restore(): freeing all working areas
Debug: 65 2 target.c:2172 target_free_all_working_areas_restore(): freeing all working areas
Debug: 66 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu configure -event gdb-flash-erase-start 
    halt

Debug: 67 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - adapter speed 500
Debug: 69 2 core.c:1822 jtag_config_khz(): handle jtag khz
Debug: 70 2 core.c:1785 adapter_khz_to_speed(): convert khz to interface specific speed value
Debug: 71 2 core.c:1785 adapter_khz_to_speed(): convert khz to interface specific speed value
Debug: 72 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - adapter srst delay 100
Debug: 74 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 75 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 76 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - init
Debug: 78 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - target init
Debug: 80 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - target names
Debug: 81 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu cget -event gdb-flash-erase-start
Debug: 82 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu cget -event gdb-flash-write-end
Debug: 83 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu configure -event gdb-flash-write-end reset halt
Debug: 84 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu cget -event gdb-attach
Debug: 85 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu configure -event gdb-attach halt 1000
Debug: 86 2 target.c:1639 handle_target_init_command(): Initializing targets...
Debug: 87 2 hla_target.c:193 adapter_init_target(): adapter_init_target
Debug: 88 2 semihosting_common.c:99 semihosting_common_init():  
Debug: 89 2 hla_interface.c:109 hl_interface_init(): hl_interface_init
Debug: 90 2 hla_layout.c:95 hl_layout_init(): hl_layout_init
Debug: 91 2 core.c:1785 adapter_khz_to_speed(): convert khz to interface specific speed value
Debug: 92 2 core.c:1789 adapter_khz_to_speed(): have interface set up
Debug: 93 2 core.c:1785 adapter_khz_to_speed(): convert khz to interface specific speed value
Debug: 94 2 core.c:1789 adapter_khz_to_speed(): have interface set up
Info : 95 2 core.c:1565 adapter_init(): clock speed 500 kHz
Debug: 96 2 openocd.c:143 handle_init_command(): Debug Adapter init complete
Debug: 97 2 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport init
Debug: 99 2 transport.c:229 handle_transport_init(): handle_transport_init
Debug: 100 2 hla_transport.c:156 hl_transport_init(): hl_transport_init
Debug: 101 2 hla_transport.c:173 hl_transport_init(): current transport hla_swd
Debug: 102 2 hla_interface.c:42 hl_interface_open(): hl_interface_open
Debug: 103 2 hla_layout.c:40 hl_layout_open(): hl_layout_open
Debug: 104 2 stlink_usb.c:2819 stlink_usb_open(): stlink_usb_open
Debug: 105 2 stlink_usb.c:2833 stlink_usb_open(): transport: 4 vid: 0x0483 pid: 0x3744 serial: 
Debug: 106 2 stlink_usb.c:2833 stlink_usb_open(): transport: 4 vid: 0x0483 pid: 0x3748 serial: 
Debug: 107 2 stlink_usb.c:2833 stlink_usb_open(): transport: 4 vid: 0x0483 pid: 0x374b serial: 
Debug: 108 2 stlink_usb.c:2833 stlink_usb_open(): transport: 4 vid: 0x0483 pid: 0x374d serial: 
Debug: 109 2 stlink_usb.c:2833 stlink_usb_open(): transport: 4 vid: 0x0483 pid: 0x374e serial: 
Debug: 110 2 stlink_usb.c:2833 stlink_usb_open(): transport: 4 vid: 0x0483 pid: 0x374f serial: 
Debug: 111 2 stlink_usb.c:2833 stlink_usb_open(): transport: 4 vid: 0x0483 pid: 0x3752 serial: 
Debug: 112 2 stlink_usb.c:2833 stlink_usb_open(): transport: 4 vid: 0x0483 pid: 0x3753 serial: 
Info : 113 5 stlink_usb.c:1102 stlink_usb_version(): STLINK V2J29S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Debug: 114 5 stlink_usb.c:1323 stlink_usb_exit_mode(): MODE: 0x01
Info : 115 5 stlink_usb.c:1134 stlink_usb_check_voltage(): Target voltage: 3.197910
Debug: 116 5 stlink_usb.c:1391 stlink_usb_init_mode(): MODE: 0x01
Debug: 117 5 stlink_usb.c:2606 stlink_dump_speed_map(): Supported clock speeds are:
Debug: 118 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 4000 kHz
Debug: 119 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 1800 kHz
Debug: 120 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 1200 kHz
Debug: 121 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 950 kHz
Debug: 122 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 480 kHz
Debug: 123 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 240 kHz
Debug: 124 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 125 kHz
Debug: 125 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 100 kHz
Debug: 126 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 50 kHz
Debug: 127 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 25 kHz
Debug: 128 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 15 kHz
Debug: 129 5 stlink_usb.c:2609 stlink_dump_speed_map(): 5 kHz
Debug: 130 18 stlink_usb.c:1450 stlink_usb_init_mode(): MODE: 0x02
Debug: 131 20 stlink_usb.c:3238 stlink_usb_open_ap(): AP 0 enabled
Debug: 132 23 stlink_usb.c:2990 stlink_usb_open(): Using TAR autoincrement: 4096
Debug: 133 23 core.c:640 adapter_system_reset(): SRST line released
Debug: 134 217 hla_interface.c:67 hl_interface_init_target(): hl_interface_init_target
Debug: 135 217 stlink_usb.c:1683 stlink_usb_idcode(): IDCODE: 0x2BA01477
Debug: 136 217 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - dap init
Debug: 138 217 arm_dap.c:106 dap_init_all(): Initializing all DAPs ...
Debug: 139 217 openocd.c:160 handle_init_command(): Examining targets...
Debug: 140 217 target.c:1827 target_call_event_callbacks(): target event 19 (examine-start) for core sam3.cpu
Debug: 141 217 hla_target.c:603 adapter_read_memory(): adapter_read_memory 0xe000ed00 4 1
Debug: 142 220 target.c:2589 target_read_u32(): address: 0xe000ed00, value: 0x412fc230
Debug: 143 220 cortex_m.c:2001 cortex_m_examine(): Cortex-M3 r2p0 processor detected
Debug: 144 220 cortex_m.c:2012 cortex_m_examine(): cpuid: 0x412fc230
Debug: 145 220 hla_target.c:603 adapter_read_memory(): adapter_read_memory 0xe000edf0 4 1
Debug: 146 222 target.c:2589 target_read_u32(): address: 0xe000edf0, value: 0x00030003
Debug: 147 222 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe000edfc, value: 0x01000000
Debug: 148 222 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe000edfc 4 1
Debug: 149 225 hla_target.c:603 adapter_read_memory(): adapter_read_memory 0xe0002000 4 1
Debug: 150 228 target.c:2589 target_read_u32(): address: 0xe0002000, value: 0x00000260
Debug: 151 228 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe0002008, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 152 228 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe0002008 4 1
Debug: 153 230 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe000200c, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 154 230 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe000200c 4 1
Debug: 155 233 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe0002010, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 156 233 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe0002010 4 1
Debug: 157 236 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe0002014, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 158 236 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe0002014 4 1
Debug: 159 238 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe0002018, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 160 238 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe0002018 4 1
Debug: 161 241 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe000201c, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 162 241 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe000201c 4 1
Debug: 163 244 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe0002020, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 164 244 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe0002020 4 1
Debug: 165 246 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe0002024, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 166 246 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe0002024 4 1
Debug: 167 249 cortex_m.c:2116 cortex_m_examine(): FPB fpcr 0x260, numcode 6, numlit 2
Debug: 168 249 hla_target.c:603 adapter_read_memory(): adapter_read_memory 0xe0001000 4 1
Debug: 169 252 target.c:2589 target_read_u32(): address: 0xe0001000, value: 0x40000000
Debug: 170 252 cortex_m.c:1830 cortex_m_dwt_setup(): DWT_CTRL: 0x40000000
Debug: 171 252 hla_target.c:603 adapter_read_memory(): adapter_read_memory 0xe0001fbc 4 1
Debug: 172 255 target.c:2589 target_read_u32(): address: 0xe0001fbc, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 173 255 cortex_m.c:1837 cortex_m_dwt_setup(): DWT_DEVARCH: 0x0
Debug: 174 255 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe0001028, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 175 255 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe0001028 4 1
Debug: 176 257 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe0001038, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 177 257 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe0001038 4 1
Debug: 178 260 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe0001048, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 179 260 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe0001048 4 1
Debug: 180 262 target.c:2677 target_write_u32(): address: 0xe0001058, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 181 262 hla_target.c:618 adapter_write_memory(): adapter_write_memory 0xe0001058 4 1
Debug: 182 265 cortex_m.c:1886 cortex_m_dwt_setup(): DWT dwtcr 0x40000000, comp 4, watch/trigger
Info : 183 265 cortex_m.c:2126 cortex_m_examine(): sam3.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Debug: 184 265 target.c:1827 target_call_event_callbacks(): target event 21 (examine-end) for core sam3.cpu
Debug: 185 265 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - flash init
Debug: 186 268 hla_target.c:603 adapter_read_memory(): adapter_read_memory 0xe000edf8 4 1
Debug: 187 270 target.c:2589 target_read_u32(): address: 0xe000edf8, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 188 274 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r0 value 0x00101318
Debug: 189 278 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r1 value 0x20000030
Debug: 190 282 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r2 value 0x00000094
Debug: 191 286 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r3 value 0x00000000
Debug: 192 290 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r4 value 0x0001c200
Debug: 193 294 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r5 value 0x00080000
Debug: 194 298 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r6 value 0x00000000
Debug: 195 302 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r7 value 0x001012c7
Debug: 196 306 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r8 value 0x200000c4
Debug: 197 310 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r9 value 0x6b4c3728
Debug: 198 314 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r10 value 0x001012d8
Debug: 199 318 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r11 value 0x001012e8
Debug: 200 322 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r12 value 0xc978113d
Debug: 201 326 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read sp value 0x20001000
Debug: 202 330 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read lr value 0xffffffff
Debug: 203 334 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read pc value 0x0010004c
Debug: 204 338 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read xPSR value 0x01000000
Debug: 205 342 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read msp value 0x20001000
Debug: 206 346 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read psp value 0x05243bd8
Debug: 207 350 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read pmsk_bpri_fltmsk_ctrl value 0x00000000
Debug: 208 352 hla_target.c:289 adapter_debug_entry(): entered debug state in core mode: Thread at PC 0x0010004c, target->state: halted
Debug: 209 352 target.c:1827 target_call_event_callbacks(): target event 0 (gdb-halt) for core sam3.cpu
Debug: 210 352 target.c:1827 target_call_event_callbacks(): target event 1 (halted) for core sam3.cpu
Debug: 211 352 hla_target.c:331 adapter_poll(): halted: PC: 0x0010004c
Debug: 213 352 tcl.c:1385 handle_flash_init_command(): Initializing flash devices...
Debug: 214 352 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - nand init
Debug: 216 355 tcl.c:498 handle_nand_init_command(): Initializing NAND devices...
Debug: 217 355 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - pld init
Debug: 219 357 pld.c:206 handle_pld_init_command(): Initializing PLDs...
Info : 220 357 gdb_server.c:3503 gdb_target_start(): starting gdb server for sam3.cpu on 3333
Info : 221 358 server.c:312 add_service(): Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Debug: 222 358 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - reset init
Debug: 224 360 target.c:1845 target_call_reset_callbacks(): target reset 3 (init)
Debug: 225 361 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - target names
Debug: 226 361 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu invoke-event reset-start
Debug: 227 361 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 228 361 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 229 361 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu invoke-event examine-start
Debug: 230 361 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu arp_examine allow-defer
Debug: 231 361 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu invoke-event examine-end
Debug: 232 361 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu invoke-event reset-assert-pre
Debug: 233 361 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 234 361 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu arp_reset assert 1
Debug: 235 361 target.c:2172 target_free_all_working_areas_restore(): freeing all working areas
Debug: 236 361 hla_target.c:344 hl_assert_reset(): hl_assert_reset
Debug: 237 382 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu invoke-event reset-assert-post
Debug: 238 382 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu invoke-event reset-deassert-pre
Debug: 239 382 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 240 382 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu arp_reset deassert 1
Debug: 241 382 target.c:2172 target_free_all_working_areas_restore(): freeing all working areas
Debug: 242 382 hla_target.c:403 hl_deassert_reset(): hl_deassert_reset
Debug: 243 382 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu invoke-event reset-deassert-post
Debug: 244 382 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 245 382 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu was_examined
Debug: 246 382 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu arp_waitstate halted 1000
Debug: 247 385 hla_target.c:603 adapter_read_memory(): adapter_read_memory 0xe000edf8 4 1
Debug: 248 388 target.c:2589 target_read_u32(): address: 0xe000edf8, value: 0x00000000
Debug: 249 392 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r0 value 0x00101318
Debug: 250 396 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r1 value 0x20000020
Debug: 251 400 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r2 value 0x00000094
Debug: 252 404 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r3 value 0x00000000
Debug: 253 408 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r4 value 0x0001c200
Debug: 254 412 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r5 value 0x00080000
Debug: 255 415 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r6 value 0x00000000
Debug: 256 419 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r7 value 0x001012c7
Debug: 257 423 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r8 value 0x200000c4
Debug: 258 427 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r9 value 0x6b4c3728
Debug: 259 431 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r10 value 0x001012d8
Debug: 260 435 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r11 value 0x001012e8
Debug: 261 439 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read r12 value 0xc978113d
Debug: 262 443 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read sp value 0x20001000
Debug: 263 447 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read lr value 0xffffffff
Debug: 264 451 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read pc value 0x0010004c
Debug: 265 455 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read xPSR value 0x01000000
Debug: 266 459 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read msp value 0x20001000
Debug: 267 463 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read psp value 0x05243bd8
Debug: 268 467 armv7m.c:341 armv7m_read_core_reg(): read pmsk_bpri_fltmsk_ctrl value 0x00000000
Debug: 269 469 hla_target.c:289 adapter_debug_entry(): entered debug state in core mode: Thread at PC 0x0010004c, target->state: halted
Debug: 270 469 target.c:1827 target_call_event_callbacks(): target event 0 (gdb-halt) for core sam3.cpu
Debug: 271 469 target.c:1827 target_call_event_callbacks(): target event 1 (halted) for core sam3.cpu
User : 272 469 armv7m.c:706 armv7m_arch_state(): target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x0010004c msp: 0x20001000
Debug: 273 469 hla_target.c:331 adapter_poll(): halted: PC: 0x0010004c
Debug: 274 469 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu curstate
Debug: 275 469 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - transport select
Debug: 276 469 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu was_examined
Debug: 277 469 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu arp_waitstate halted 5000
Debug: 278 472 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu invoke-event reset-init
Debug: 279 472 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - sam3.cpu invoke-event reset-end
Debug: 280 474 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - echo ** Programming Started **
User : 282 477 command.c:769 jim_echo(): ** Programming Started **
Debug: 283 477 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - flash write_image erase /home/me/path/a.hex
Debug: 284 477 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - usage flash
User : 286 480 command.c:870 command_help_show(): flashUser : 287 480 command.c:879 command_help_show(): 
User : 288 480 command.c:833 command_help_show_indent():   User : 289 480 command.c:870 command_help_show(): flash bankUser : 290 480 command.c:876 command_help_show():  User : 291 480 command.c:849 command_help_show_wrap(): bank_id driver_name base_address size_bytes chip_width_bytes
User : 292 480 command.c:833 command_help_show_indent():   User : 293 480 command.c:833 command_help_show_indent():   User : 294 480 command.c:833 command_help_show_indent():   User : 295 480 command.c:833 command_help_show_indent():   User : 296 480 command.c:833 command_help_show_indent():   User : 297 480 command.c:833 command_help_show_indent():   User : 298 480 command.c:849 command_help_show_wrap(): bus_width_bytes target [driver_options ...]
User : 299 480 command.c:833 command_help_show_indent():   User : 300 480 command.c:870 command_help_show(): flash banksUser : 301 480 command.c:879 command_help_show(): 
User : 302 480 command.c:833 command_help_show_indent():   User : 303 480 command.c:870 command_help_show(): flash initUser : 304 480 command.c:879 command_help_show(): 
User : 305 480 command.c:833 command_help_show_indent():   User : 306 480 command.c:870 command_help_show(): flash listUser : 307 480 command.c:879 command_help_show(): 
User : 308 480 command.c:870 command_help_show(): gdb_flash_programUser : 309 480 command.c:876 command_help_show():  User : 310 480 command.c:849 command_help_show_wrap(): ('enable'|'disable')
User : 311 480 command.c:870 command_help_show(): nandUser : 312 480 command.c:879 command_help_show(): 
User : 313 480 command.c:870 command_help_show(): programUser : 314 480 command.c:876 command_help_show():  User : 315 480 command.c:849 command_help_show_wrap(): <filename> [address] [pre-verify] [verify] [reset] [exit]
Error: 316 480 command.c:1016 run_usage(): invalid subcommand "write_image erase /home/me/path/a.hex"
Debug: 317 480 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - echo ** Programming Failed **
User : 319 482 command.c:769 jim_echo(): ** Programming Failed **
Debug: 320 482 command.c:146 script_debug(): command - shutdown error
User : 322 485 server.c:755 handle_shutdown_command(): shutdown command invoked
Debug: 323 485 command.c:629 run_command(): Command 'shutdown' failed with error code -4
User : 324 485 command.c:694 command_run_line(): embedded:startup.tcl:583: Error: 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 583
Debug: 325 485 target.c:2172 target_free_all_working_areas_restore(): freeing all working areas
Debug: 326 485 hla_interface.c:117 hl_interface_quit(): hl_interface_quit
Debug: 327 485 stlink_usb.c:1323 stlink_usb_exit_mode(): MODE: 0x02


Try to execute this as super user with the command sudo. Add -d at the end of the command for additional debug output. Provide the full path of a.elf

@StefanWyss I am running the commands as super user. I uploaded debug logs.
